# Contiguity of uniform random regular graphs and uniform random regular graphs which have a perfect matching

Tags: pr.probability, random-graphs

Let us consider $\cal{G}_{_{n,d}}$ as the uniform probability space of d-regular graphs
on the n vertices $\{1, \ldots, n \}$ (where $dn$ is even). We say that an event $H_{_{n}}$ occurs a.a.s. (asymptotically almost surely) if $\mathbf{P}_{_{\cal{G}}}(H_{_{n}}) \longrightarrow 1$ as  $n ⟶ \infty$.

Also, suppose $(\cal{G}_{_{n}})_{_{n ≥ 1}}$ and $(\cal{\hat{G}}_{_{n}})_{_{n ≥ 1}}$ are two sequences of probability spaces such that $\cal{G}_{_{n}}$ and $\cal{\hat{G}}_{_{n}}$ are differ only in the probabilities. We say that these sequences are *contiguous* if a sequence of events $A_{_{n}}$ is a.a.s. true in $\cal{\hat{G}}_{_{n}}$ if and only if it is true in $\cal{\hat{G}}_{_{n}}$, in which case we write
$$\cal{G}_{_{n}} \approx \cal{\hat{G}}_{_{n}}.$$

**Thorem**. (Bollobas) For any fixed $d \geq 3$, $G_{_{n}} ∈ \cal{G}_{_{n,d}}$ a.a.s has a perfect matching.

Using $\cal{G}^p_{_{n,d}}$ to denote the uniform probability space of d-regular graphs **which have a perfect matching** on the n vertices $\{1, \ldots, n \}$, is it true to conclude from the above theorem that $\cal{G}_{_{n,d}} \approx \cal{G}^p_{_{n,d}}$?

Comment: It seems that this follows immediately from the elementary inequality $$|P[A] - P[A\,|\,B]| \leq P[B^c]\,.$$  Take $A$ to be your $A_n$ and $B$ the event that it has a perfect matching.

Comment: I think you are right @MarcusM.